# jsoup exception for a timeout

Tags: java, jsoup

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:391)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:157)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:146)
```

==
I am seeing this at :

```
try
{
..
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(recevurl).get();
..

}
catch (IOException| NullPointerException ee)
{
ee.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am not getting how to get ride of this exception ?
also is there a way I can handle this? I was thinking that the IOException  will handle this!!

Comment: @The Learner- Are you behind a proxy? if yes then set the java proxy setting and try, otherwise increasing timeout will not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(recevurl).timeout(3000).get();`

Comment: Thanks Alrex. it is giving the method timeout(int) is not defined for type doc

Comment: Wrong order. Try `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(recevurl).timeout(3000).get();` instead.

Comment: @ollo Thanks! I hope this will be helpful (in my case it was).

Comment: May add 0 as timeout(infinite timeout)